# How to import configurable product through csv in Magento?

Tags: magento, import, product, dataflow

I need to import Configurable product and Grouped product through csv in Magento

So can anyone please provide csv demo file for that? either using `import/export` or `dataflow profiles`. or suggest something for that.

Thanks

Comment: Dataflow is quite good. But I prefer magmi (Magento Mass Importer). [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/).Magmi is incredibly fast and reliable and offers You everything that you may need like, custom options import, grouped and virtual products. And the best part you don't have to create a different CSV format. Your dataflow format will work it.